# extracting the ids assigned to a list of user ids

Tags: php, mysql, explode

Above question may be confusing so let me explain it. I have a table with structure similar as below :

```
form_id         bank_ids 

   1            5,6,7,8
   2            7,10
   3            4,7,9
   4            5,8,1
```

Now suppose I want to extract the form ids assigned to bank_id `7`, how can I able to extract it?

Comment: You have an array stored in sql? or you have multiple columns?

Comment: No its not an array. Its a string `VARCHAR`

Comment: I'd change the structure of your table, to be easier to search. Include one Auto Incrementing row, and then form_id and bank_id and just have 4 rows with form_id 1, 2 rows with form_id 2, etc. It will make it easier to search, and if you have to merge tables at some point, it will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a builtin function for that called [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('7', bank_ids) > 0
```

You should properly normalize your table.

**UPDATE**

if you want to use `LIKE`, you need to concatenate `,` on both side. eg

```
WHERE CONCAT(',', bank_ids, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', '7', ',%')
```

Comment: This (new to me) function will come in handy for me one day. *"Learning curve"*