# How to see if a result from the database matches my values in the array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Hi guys i have been trying to rap my head around this for some time now. What I'm trying to achieve is get some data from my database, store it in a variable and compare it to a value that is stored in my array. 
Problem is it keeps returning the wrong output. From the `SQL` query below, the `mysql_result $total_cat` returns a value of **`16`**. Once this value is stored, the code is meant to output `echo "this value is in the array";` but its not working.
Where am i going wrong?

**This is my Code**

Create an array to store my values in

```
$lunchbox = array(12,13,14,16,20,24,33,32);
```

Set up my SQL database query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$the_persons_id'");
```

Catch my result and store it in a variable

```
$total_cat = mysql_result($query,0,"category_id");
```

Clean my result

```
$total_cat  = str_replace("|", " ", $total_cat);
```

Check if my sql result matches my any of my results stored in my array

```
if (in_array($total_cat, $lunchbox)) {
    echo "this value is in the array";
}else{
    echo "this value is not in the array";
```

Comment: do you mean to say there is only one column in the table that has a value of 16 for your query parameters? curious since i see you are doing a `select *`

Comment: how does *category_id* looks like in the database? Your "cleaning" makes me assume, it might look like 1|2|16 ... So, you would actually generate "1 2 16" by "cleaning" it, which is not in the array...

Comment: Sidenote: `$total_cat  = str_replace("|", " ", $total_cat);` you're replacing `|` with a space and your array doesn't contain any spaces. In doing so, you'd either need to do `$total_cat  = str_replace("|", "", $total_cat);` or use `trim()`.

Comment: There is more than one column in the table but I'm just testing the first value that i displayed on the screen

Comment: the value prints out like this `9|16`. but im only worried about finding `16`

Comment: @dognose yes that how the data gets displayed if i run `echo "$total_cat";`

Comment: This Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/23270686/ might be of help and http://stackoverflow.com/q/23260372/

Comment: However, you may have better luck using `IN` or `FIND_IN_SET()` directly from your query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- how would i write that query can you give me an example

Comment: For `FIND_IN_SET()` see http://stackoverflow.com/q/23504764/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/22480418/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19602637/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19462626/ and for `IN()` see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm I hope this helps.

Comment: found the answer guys thanks for the help. All i needed to do was use php function substr so it would look like this `$total_cat = substr($total_cat, 1);`
`echo "$total_cat";` and the result will display as 16 making my end result evaluate to true causing my value to be found in my array. :)

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. You can post it as an answer yourself you know ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

**This is my code:**

Create an array to store my values in

```
$lunchbox = array(12,13,14,16,20,24,33,32);
```

Set up my SQL database query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$the_persons_id'");
```

Catch my result and store it in a variable

```
$total_cat = mysql_result($query,0,"category_id");
```

Clean my result

```
$total_cat  = str_replace("|", " ", $total_cat);
```

This will output as `9 16`

Now we run the php function [substr](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php) to remove the first part of the string.

```
$total_cat = substr($total_cat, 1);
```

This will give us the output of `16`

Now we check if my SQL result matches my any of my results stored in my array

```
if (in_array($total_cat, $lunchbox)) {
    echo "this value is in the array";
}else{
    echo "this value is not in the array";
```

Which it does and now my `IF` statement evaluates to `TRUE` and the code is complete.

Thanks for all the help team.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Accept your answer if it's solution. :)